# Sharepoint Cascading drop down issue

Tags: jquery, sharepoint-2010, cascadingdropdown

Cascading drop down code randomly stopped working in my New/Edit pages? I haven't changed the columns and what is weird is when I go to Page/Edit in my CEWP to Review the code it is working perfectly.

Has anyone seen this and know why this could be happening?

UPDATE: Created new "test" list with only Title and the 3 lookup columns and it is still not working.  What's odd is when I go to Page/Edit, the drop downs are cascading perfectly. I even removed the values in the 3 lookup lists that were added within the past month and still nothing happening.  I am not sure what else to do at the moment unless I completely Re-create all three lookup lists and lookup columns all over again.

Another Update:  I created 3 new lookup lists, manually added a few values in each of these.  Then created these new lookup columns in my "test" environment and still it is not working.  It only seems to be working in Page/Edit Mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I submitted a ticket to our Sharepoint Server group to look into this because something seemed odd.  I received an email response back today saying that they fixed the backend server issues regarding this.  Now it is working perfectly.  I am not sure how they fixed this, but definitely something I could not do using SPD.